# using wild card when listing directories in python

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, directory-structure

how can I use wild cars like '*' when getting a list of files inside a directory in Python?  for example, I want something like:

```
os.listdir('foo/*bar*/*.txt')
```

which would return a list of all the files ending in .txt in directories that have bar in their name inside of the foo parent directory.

how can I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for the win.